# Strip category base from URL?

Tags: permalinks, archives

Where I Place This Code Or How Can I Use This?

```
function wpa_alter_cat_links( $termlink, $term, $taxonomy ){
    if( 'category' != $taxonomy ) return $termlink;

    return str_replace( '/category', '', $termlink );
}
add_filter( 'term_link', 'wpa_alter_cat_links', 10, 3 );
```

You'll probably want to test this thoroughly for any side-effects, use at your own risk!

**EDIT** - altering just top level category links:

```
function wpa_alter_cat_links( $termlink, $term, $taxonomy ){
    if( 'category' == $taxonomy && 0 == $term->parent ){
        return str_replace( '/category', '', $termlink );
    }
    return $termlink;
}
add_filter( 'term_link', 'wpa_alter_cat_links', 10, 3 );
```

**Original Source: [Force Wordpress to Show Pages Instead of Category](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106042/force-wordpress-to-show-pages-instead-of-category/176795)**

Comment: Please don't ask for help in your title. The post title should be a smart short description of what your question is all about. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would place this code inside your theme's functions.php file.  It shouldn't really matter where in the file that you place it.

Comment: not working On theme's functions.php